# vite Bindings not found

Tags: reactjs, vite

Estoy teniendo un problema al ejecutar `npm run dev`.

```
12:29:39 [vite] Internal server error: Bindings not found.  Plugin: vite:react-swc  File: C:/Users/enzop/Desktop/myVite/src/main.jsx
     at Compiler.<anonymous>  (C:\Users\enzop\Desktop\myVite\node_modules\@swc\core\index.js:225:19)
     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
     at C:\Users\enzop\Desktop\myVite\node_modules\@swc\core\index.js:34:71

     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
     at __awaiter (C:\Users\enzop\Desktop\myVite\node_modules\@swc\core\index.js:30:12)
     at Compiler.transform  (C:\Users\enzop\Desktop\myVite\node_modules\@swc\core\index.js:202:16)
     at transform (C:\Users\enzop\Desktop\myVite\node_modules\@swc\core\index.js:344:21)
     at transformWithOptions  (file:///C:/Users/enzop/Desktop/myVite/node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-react-  swc/index.mjs:141:20)
     at TransformContext.transform  (file:///C:/Users/enzop/Desktop/myVite/node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-react-  swc/index.mjs:66:30)
     at Object.transform  (file:///C:/Users/enzop/Desktop/myVite/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep->abb4f102.js:44206:62)
```

Comment: Prueba borrar la carpeta `node_modules` de tu proyecto y luego vuélvela a instalar todas tus dependencias `npm i` En teoría tu problema se debería de solicionar.